# Maven Sonar doesn't find JRE classes when running FindBugs

Tags: maven, sonarqube, findbugs

When I run the sonar:sonar goal with Maven, FindBugs complains that some required classes were missing, which are part of the JRE.
I was expecting that this is automatically handled by the Maven dependencies.
If I run Sonar using Ant it works fine.

```
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] [09:54:35.802] Execute Findbugs 2.0.3 done: 271543 ms
[artifact:mvn] The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
[artifact:mvn]   java.lang.Enum
[artifact:mvn]   java.beans.PropertyChangeListener
[artifact:mvn]   java.lang.annotation.Annotation
[artifact:mvn]   java.util.concurrent.Callable
[artifact:mvn]   java.lang.Iterable
                 ...
```

Note: I don't know if it may have something to do, but I'm calling sonar:sonar from Ant task (artifact:mvn), because I need to run the analysis for a specific list of projects (not all modules defined in the pom are analyzed) and it was easier for me to make this script using Ant.

Comment: Have you configured the FindBugs analysis to run in its own process, or are you using the Maven process?

Comment: Seems like a pre-1.5 JVM is being used, as all the classes it can't find have been introduced with 1.5.

Comment: I'm calling the artifact:mvn using fork=true, so the Maven call is using its own process (not the Ant process). But I didn't configure anything regarding FindBugs, so it should be using the default configuration. Besides, I'm using Java 7 to run the Sonar, the JAVA_HOME is set to a JDK 7, and also the Maven java source is set to 1.7.